# TFS 2015 - Can you have multiple branches using the same solution?

Tags: tfs-2015

My current need is to be able to create a new branch from our main branch and open up the new branch solution and work off that.

What is happening, I've added my main source code files to TFS, bound the solution to source control and the application works with no problems. When I create a new branch from the main branch, with the solution from Main closed, then I try and open up the new branch solution, it binds to the main solution not the solution in the new branch. Is there a way around this?

[image: TFS Branch]

Comment: Is your solution file also part of the branch folder? Or is the solution stored in a different folder (or only locally stored)?

Comment: As jesse said we check in our .sln files so they get versioned with the branch

Comment: Jess, yes, the solution is part of the main branch folder and also the 'TestBranch' folder in TFS. I've mapped the project to my local drive, not a network drive (pretty sure this has nothing to do with it, on where you map the branches). It has been a long time since I've used TFS, obviously I am doing something wrong. If you need anymore information, let me know. Thank you for your help, much appreciated.

Comment: Just to clarify the requirements, the application is based on scheduled events, each event could have totally different requirements and we could have more that one event at a time. What I thought we could do is have a Main branch, create a new branch from Main for each scheduled event, so we are not working off only one Main branch but each event branch. Hope this makes sense. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could do this as below:

1. Created a "$/Main" folder
2. Converted it to a branch
3. Created a "$/Dev" folder
4. Branched from Main into "$/Dev"

For example, if your normal workspace maps from "$/Dev" to your local "C:\Dev" folder. And that's where you do your day to day work, and the solution files are under there.

Then when you merge forward to Main, the solution naturally comes with it.The solution doesn't refer to any branch. It contains references relative to the disk location, so it all works in any branch or any machine.

Comment: Patrick, just so I understand, when converting the Main folder to a branch and then branching from Main to the Dev folder, the Dev folder stays as a folder or should this become also a branch? Thanks

Comment: I followed your instructions, and in addition I created a Releases folder in which I branched the same project/solution with a new name, then when trying to open up the project/solution in the releases folder, it prompted me to bind to source control which I did. I did some modifying and the project/solution is independant of the Main solution. I did the same thing, branch from Main to the releases folder, gave the project/solution a different name, tried to open up the solution, TFS prompted me to bind to source control, said yes, I reloaded all projects but no success.

Comment: @William when converting the Main folder to a branch and then branching from Main to the Dev folder, it based on your Dev folder exists or not, if the Dev folder do not exists, you will get a new Dev **branch**. If the Dev folder already exists, you will get an error message  `The  item xxx/Dev` already exists`.

Comment: @William According to your description, sounds like the expected  behavior, `rename`  is a "delete" + "add"  operation in TFS. If you do a merge from main again, there will be two solutions in your release branch. This will mess up your release branch. Why you have to rename and do some modifying on the original solution? A clean   way to do is directly creating a new different solution on your release branch.

Comment: Patrick, I’m looking after an event application, each event could have different requirements, so you have to code for each specific event independently and see it as a ‘new’ application. In addition, you can have multiple events at the same time, so what I would like to do is have the Main branch and then just create new branches and work off the new branches independently for each specific event. If what you are saying that I can’t do that, I guess I would need to create a new project for each event and work that way, unless you know something else that I can do. Thanks